# How to refactor if statements with a Map using Java 8 Lambdas

Tags: java, dictionary, validation, lambda, hashmap

I would like to know how i can refactor my code using a Map Data Structure and Lambdas.

Here is my method:

```
private void validateUserFields(User user) {
    if(user.getName() == null){
        throw new RuntimeException("The user's name cannot be null");
    }
    if(user.getLastName() == null){
        throw new RuntimeException("The user's lastName cannot be null");
    }
    if(user.getDni() == null){
        throw new RuntimeException("The user's dni cannot be null");
    }
    if(user.getVehicle() == null){
        throw new RuntimeException("The user's vehicle cannot be null");
    }
}
```

I expect a elegant an a simple way to refactor my code.

Comment: Could you please add the code of the current attempt you've made to refactor this, so we can see where you got stuck and may help you better with your approach?

Comment: I'm new using lamdas, Map datastructures and stack overflow, so i'm still learning how to refactor imperative code, but if you have a proposal it will be grateful with you :)

Comment: There is a way of validating the object, which is both elegant and efficient: using Lombok's `@NonNull` + `@Builder` annotations. But that has nothing to do with maps or lambdas. https://projectlombok.org/features/NonNull

Comment: @英語は苦手 when you're creating an object using lombok `@Builder` and you have `@NonNull` annotated fields, calling `.build()` throws exception.

Comment: @英語は苦手 that's exactly my point, don't do in in a method, that's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a map of validations:

```
private static Map<String, Function<User, ?>> VALIDATIONS = Map.of(
        "name", User::getName,
        "lastName", User::getLastName,
        "dni", User::getDni,
        "vehicle", User::getVehicle
);

private void validateUserFields(User user) {
    VALIDATIONS.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().apply(user) == null)
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
        .map(field -> String.format("The user's %s cannot be null", field))
        .map(RuntimeException::new)
        .findFirst()
        .ifPresent(e -> {
            throw e;
        });
}
```

or this briefer version that bypasses the use of method references:

```
private void validateUserFields(User user) {
    VALIDATIONS.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().apply(user) == null)
        .findFirst()
        .ifPresent(e -> {throw new RuntimeException("The user's " + e.getKey() + " cannot be null");});
}
```

I don't know if it's "elegant", but it is scaleable and flexible.

Comment: Looks elegant to me :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what you asked for, I dont't know if it's elegant, your method looks fine as is to me, the only thing I would change is to create an InvalidUserException which takes in the name of the null field.

This can be a good exercise to understand data structures and the Functional Interface, but I wouldn't do it this way for something as simple as this.

You could check out the simplified strategy pattern with lambdas.

EDIT: This could be useful if you have a very complex validation logic on many fields, but simply for checking that no field is null I agree with using the Lombok approach as suggested in the comments.

```
public class App {
    public static HashMap<String, Predicate<User>> VALIDATION_FUNCTIONS = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        VALIDATION_FUNCTIONS.put("NAME", user -> user.getName() != null);
        VALIDATION_FUNCTIONS.put("MOREFIELDS", user -> user.getMorefields() != null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        validateUserFields(new User());
    }

    private static void validateUserFields(User user) {
         VALIDATION_FUNCTIONS.forEach((field,function) -> {
             if (!function.test(user))
                 throw new RuntimeException(field + " is null");
         });
    }

    @Getter
    @NoArgsConstructor
    static class User {
        private String name;
        private String morefields;
    }
}
```